# Android 4.4.4 Webview on Nexus 5 goes blank (or gets frozen) sometimes

Tags: android, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat, hybrid-mobile-app

I have an hybrid app which has a navigation drawer to go to different links, and a webview to load the content.
The problem that recently surfaced is that sometimes when you resume the app from background on Nexus 5(Android 4.4.4), the webview goes completely blank and there's no way to recover from that state. Clicking on different links in the navigation drawers does nothing. It does even try to load the page. You can't recover until you force kill the app or reinstall.
It happens very intermittently and I have been able to find out the concrete reproducible steps for this. It start happening couple of days back, so I doubt it could be due to the recent update on Chrome Browser, but I'm not very sure.

Anyone else facing similar issue? Any pointers on how can I fix it?

Comment: WebView is not getting re-attached to the host process. Check for that, and re-attach (re-create) if needed.